# Joining data.table with by argument

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.table `dx` and `dy`

```
dx <- data.table(a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2), b = 3:8)
dy <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2), c = 7:9)
```

I want to join `dy` to each row of `dx`, and below is the desired output

```
data.table(plyr::ddply(dx, c("a", "b"), function(d) merge(d, dy, by = "a")))
    a b c
 1: 1 3 7
 2: 1 3 8
 3: 1 4 7
 4: 1 4 8
 5: 1 5 7
 6: 1 5 8
 7: 1 6 7
 8: 1 6 8
 9: 2 7 9
10: 2 8 9
```

However, I failed to make the output only using operation inside `[]` of `data.table` or `merge`? I have tired

```
merge(dx, dy, by = "a", all = TRUE)
```

**Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 10 rows; more than 9 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.**

```
dy[dx,on="a"]
```

**Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 10 rows; more than 9 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.**

```
dx[, merge(dy, by = "a"), by = c("a", "b")]
```

**Error in is.data.table(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default**

```
dx[, merge(.SD, dy, by = "a"), by = c("a", "b")]
```

**Error in merge.data.table(.SD, dy, by = "a") : 
  Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y**

How can I do it actually?

Thanks!

Comment: Try  `dy[dx,on="a"]`.

Comment: @nicola I have modified my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the error message tells you exactly how to proceed. Which part of "If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE." didn't you understand?

Comment: you are right, I should read more carefully the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, I understood your requirement correctly, There is a direct merge option that you can use,

```
dx <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2,2), b = 3:6)
dy <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2), c = 7:9)
merge(x = dx, y = dy, by = "a", all = TRUE)
```

It gives your desired output that you mentioned.
[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

I hope it clears your doubt if not, I am sory.

Comment: Thanks! But I have just modified my question.

Comment: Try this command hope it may sole your problem dx[dy, allow.cartesian = TRUE]

Answer (score 18):

Because of multiple 1s, the error is coming. In default merge, i.e the implementation for data.frames, `allow.cartesian=TRUE` by default. But in the data.table implemetation, this is not the case. Hence, if you run the below code it will give you merge output.

```
merge(dx, dy, by = "a", all = TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
```

The above code will give you the output that you want.